# Invariant transformation's complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be an inner product space.
Let T : V-> V be linear and U a subspace of V . If T (U) ⊆ U, then T(U⊥)⊆ U⊥

I began with showing that (T(u), u') = 0, but didn't know how to show that (u, T(u')) = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is not true unless we are given further information about $T$ (e.g. $T$ is normal or self-adjoint). As a counterexample, consider $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$, $T(x,y) = (y,0)$. We see that the span of $(1,0)$ is an invariant subspace, but the orthogonal complement (spanned by $(0,1)$) is not.